# Is the curvature of spacetime zero, in the center of a Kerr black hole?

Tags: black-holes, curvature, kerr-metric

In a [Kerr black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_black_hole) the singularity in the center has become a ringularity. Roughly said a singularity that is not point-like but circle-like. The curvature blows up not at the exact center of the Schwarzschild surface but around it. Is the true center of the hole a place with no gravity? Or will matter rush from there outward to the infinite depth of the ring? Will there even be matter inside the ring?

Comment: “*a singularity that is not point-like*” - The Schwarzschild singularity is not “point-like”. It is a widespread misconception based on the Newtonian view of a gravitational collapse to a “point” in space that exists in time, therefore representing a timeline (timelike line). In GR, the collapse flips space and time around making this singularity a “point” in time that happens everywhere in space along one dimension, therefore representing an infinitely long line in space (spacelike line) that exists only at one moment in time. The Schwarzschild singularity is not “point-like”, but momentary.

Comment: @safesphere Can we say there is litterally a hole in space at infinity? Or a circular hole for a Kerr? What does the middle look like?

Answer (score 1):

The curvature invariant called Kretschman scalar for a Kerr black hole is $\rm K=$

$$\rm -\frac{384 \left(a^2 \cos (2 \theta )+a^2-2 r^2\right) \left(a^4+a^2 \cos (2 \theta ) \left(a^2 \cos (2 \theta )+2 a^2-28 r^2\right)-28 a^2 r^2+4 r^4\right)}{\left(a^2 \cos (2 \theta )+a^2+2 r^2\right)^6}$$

and the geometric center in the middle of the ring is at $\rm r=0, \ \theta=0$. The singular ring is at $\rm r=0, \ \theta=\pi/2$, which is not the same in Boyer Lindquist coordinates, where the cartesian $\rm R=\sqrt{r^2+a^2} \ \sin \theta$, so the center is at $\rm R=0$ while the singularity is at $\rm R=a$. The Kretschmann scalar is not $0$ in the center of the ring, see the plot for $\rm -K$ at $\rm r\to 0, \ \theta=0$ from $\rm a=0$ to $\rm a=1$ (in natural units):

[image: curvature between the ring singularity of a Kerr black hole, yukterez.net]

The larger the spin $\rm a$, the smaller the curvature $\rm K$ at the center though, but it doesn't go to zero. The curvature is also lowest in the center, and at the ring itself it blows up to infinity, see the plot for $\rm -K$ with $\rm r\to 0, \ a=1$ from $\rm \theta=0$ to $\rm \theta=\pi/2$:

[image: curvature in the center of a Kerr black hole, yukterez.net]

The gravitational acceleration between the ring is repulsive, and an observer attempting to go through needs high kinetic energy for it, a freefaller from infinity for example does not have enough speed to go through, but a photon or an ultrarelativistic observer can (assuming the maximally extended spacetime as it is depicted [here](https://jila.colorado.edu/%7Eajsh/insidebh/penrose.html#kerr) and explained [here](http://www.madore.org/%7Edavid/math/kerr.html#course.negspace)).